# Ant-Junit classpath from property

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have the following Ant target and path elements in the project.

```
<project>
.....
<path id="MyProject.classpath" location="${class.path}">
    <pathelement location="${output.directory}/ant-junit.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${output.directory}/junit.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${output.directory}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <pathelement location="${class.path}"/> <!-- This did not work -->
    <dirset dir="${dest.path}">         
    </dirset>
</path>

<path id="classpath.test">
    <fileset dir="${output.directory}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="test">      
    <echo>In Test</echo>  
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
    <junit>
        <classpath refid="MyProject.classpath">
        </classpath>           
        <batchtest todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false"/>
            <formatter type="plain" />
            <fileset dir="${src.path}">
                <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>    
    </junit>
</target>
....
</project>
```

I have a property `class.path` pointing to a bunch of jars like below. I'd like to use this `class.path` (created by IDE) property as the class-path to the above `junit` test's classpath, I've tried a few things, it did not work. Could someone point me to the right direction?

```
<condition property="class.path" value="C:/tools/bea/jdk142_19/jre/lib/rt.jar;C:/tools/bea/jdk142_19/jre/lib/jsse.jar;C:/tools/bea/jdk142_19/jre/lib/jce.jar;C:/tools/bea/jdk142_19/lib/tools.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/knex.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/common/lib/log4j.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/debugging.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/javelin/lib/javelin.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/wlw-lang.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/weblogic.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/common/eval/pointbase/lib/pbserver44.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/common/eval/pointbase/lib/pbclient44.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/webservices.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/webserviceclient.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/webserviceclient+ssl.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/wli.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/xbean.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/wlxbean.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/xqrl.jar;${platformhome.local.directory}/server/lib/netui/netui-compiler.jar;${app.local.directory}/APP-INF/lib/CommonUtilities.jar;${app.local.directory}/APP-INF/lib/junit.jar;${app.local.directory}/APP-INF/lib/log4j.jar">
       <or>
         <os family="windows"/>
         <os name="SunOS"/>
       </or>
     </condition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<pathelement location= ...>`: The `location` attribute specifies a **single file** or directory relative to the project's base directory (or an absolute filename), while the `path` attribute accepts **colon- or semicolon-separated lists of locations**.
The path attribute is intended to be used with predefined paths - in any other case, multiple elements with location attributes should be preferred.

..from [**HERE**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path)

using `<pathelement path="${class.path}" />` should work, *unless there are further errors*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you've implemented the Ant classpath. Here's mine, which hopefully will help you:

```
<path id="project_classpath">
   <fileset dir="${dir_sandbox_jar_dependencies}" includes="*.jar"/>
   <pathelement location="${build.class.dir}"/>
</path>
```

And then I use it with

```
<java classname="some.java.class" failonerror="true" classpathref="project_classpath">
   <arg value="hello"/>
</java>
```

`classpathref` is a parameter for many tasks, such as [`javac`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html), [`java`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html), and [`javadoc`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html)

It's also accepted--I think--as a [nested element](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html#nested) in JUnit task.

Comment: Hello aliteralmind, the ant classpath is within the build.xml file. I need to set the classpath to the junit task. But the path is in one of the property class.path.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not positive. I hoped sharing what I use might help.